# In react-native how Can we auto detect links and phone numbers in string and highlight them in text

Tags: react-native, text, hyperlink

In react-native application how can we detect the links and phone numbers in text string and highlight the links and phone numbers in the text and how can we assign call functionality to phone numbers and redirecting links to browser from text string itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package called [react-native-autolink](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autolink). It may help you to achieve what you want. Parses text and wraps URLs, phone numbers, emails, social handles, hashtags, and more with Text nodes and onPress handlers. And it's all fully customizable